# How to make an installer for my C# application?

Tags: c#, winforms, installation

I have created an application ([C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29), [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms)) on [Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008), and now I want to make installer of this application. How can this be done?

I want my installer to

- Copy all the files that my
  application is using to a user
  chosen path (copy the files to
  the chosen, some for the server-side application and
  some for the client side).
- Also install [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) 3.5
- Check for [SQL Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server) or [SQL Server Express Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Express)

How can I do it?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

1. Add a new install project to your solution.
2. Add targets from all projects you want to be installed.
3. Configure pre-requirements and choose "Check for .NET 3.5 and SQL Express" option. Choose the location from where missing components must be installed.
4. Configure your installer settings - company name, version, copyright, etc.
5. Build and go!

Comment: Will this allow MSI feature? sounds like it's needed - "copy the files on choice..." maybe you can get away with 2 different installers? but if install project doesn't provide features, go with wix.

Comment: If you need some specific install logic you can write some code (and add your own forms) that will do the work you need.

Comment: "Add targets from all projects you want to be installed."
how man.. i dont knw anything about it...

Comment: "Add a new install project" ... the only option I have under Setup and Deployment is InstallShield Limited Edition. That doesn't seem to be what you're suggesting - is there a step missing, some package I need to install or something?

Comment: I might be a bit late but installer projects are no longer supported in VS 2012 and up. You'll have to utilise WiX or other third party means.

Comment: If you are using VS2015 or VS2017 and 'Setup and Deployment' is missing from the 'Other Projects Types' tree you can install it from here: [VS2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=visualstudioclient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects) or [VS2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=visualstudioclient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects)

Comment: @sashaeve: Is it possible to code a custom installer to suite my needs? Because none of the third-party tools are useful to me. To name a few, I have tried Advanced Installer, InstallForge, Inno Setup, Wix, etc. Specifically, I need to install .net framework on the customer's system and I need a bit of customizations like Flat Modern UI, Activation connected to my server, etc.

Answer (score 18):

Generally speaking, it's recommended to use MSI-based installations on Windows. Thus, if you're ready to invest a fair bit of time, [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) is the way to go.

If you want something which is much more simpler, go with [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php).

Comment: Wix is the way to go if you need more control over your MSI. However, it does require more effort to learn. As per Wix's documentation, MS Office also uses Wix to create their installs.

Answer (score 11):

There are several methods, two of which are as follows. Provide a custom installer or a setup project.

**Here is how to create a custom installer**

```
[RunInstaller(true)]
public class MyInstaller : Installer
{
    public HelloInstaller()
        : base()
    {
    }

    public override void Commit(IDictionary mySavedState)
    {
        base.Commit(mySavedState);
        System.IO.File.CreateText("Commit.txt");
    }

    public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
    {
        base.Install(stateSaver);
        System.IO.File.CreateText("Install.txt");
    }

    public override void Uninstall(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.Uninstall(savedState);
        File.Delete("Commit.txt");
        File.Delete("Install.txt");
    }

    public override void Rollback(IDictionary savedState)
    {
        base.Rollback(savedState);
        File.Delete("Install.txt");
    }
}
```

**To add a setup project**

- Menu *file* -> *New* -> *Project* --> *Other Projects Types* --> *Setup
  and Deployment*
- Set properties of the project, using the properties window

The article *[How to create a Setup package by using Visual Studio .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353)* provides the details.

Comment: how do you expect to run this code when .NET 3.5 is going to be installed in you insaller

Comment: @Moon you could say in the program description that it required .NET XY

Answer (score 4):

For Visual Studio 2022 Community, you have to add Microsoft's Installer package separately. It's available for free from the [VS Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2022InstallerProjects).

Answer (score 3):

Why invent wheels yourself while there is a car ready for you? I just find this tools super easy and intuitive to use: Advanced Installer. This [one minute video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tz_maDNntAk) should be enough to impress you. Here is the [illustrative user guide](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-professional.html).

Comment: Just for everyone who will come across this (Advanced Installer), it is a product that must be purchased.  So you'll have to figure it whether it's worth it -- pay the money, or put in the work to learn WIX, which is free, powerful and open source, but has a steep learning curve.  If you are bringing in a decent piece of change already, it probably will be better to try the Advanced Installer (once again depending on how much power you need).

Comment: Video is not available anymore.