# How to ship a Windows Forms application to a client without .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, setup-deployment

This is about the deployment of a [Windows Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms) application. I have created a Windows Forms application, but I'm not sure if the users have installed .NET version 4. I have put my Windows Forms application at my website and the users will download it to their desktop.

How do I automate the process of downloading and installing .NET 4 if the users have not installed it? What are the recommended ways of deploying Windows Forms applications to users?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

> ClickOnce deployment allows you to publish Windows-based applications to a Web server or network file share for simplified installation.

You just need to define which prerequisites you want to include in bootstraper, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h4k032e1.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You could [define prerequisites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eh4aaa5.aspx) in your Setup And Deployment Project.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide an installer and mark [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) as a prerequisite. See Stack Overflow question *[How to make an installer for my C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251062)* (.NET 3.5, but the idea is the same).

Answer (score 1):

You could always download and include [the .NET 4 redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17718). It about 40 MB so it may not be the most optimal solution, but it may be the easiest for the client.