# Create custom installer/updater

Tags: c#, installation

I was wondering if there were any tutorials/tips on making a custom installer from scratch in VC#. And yes, I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251062/c-sharp-how-to-make-an-installer-for-my-application) question, but that's not what I want. I want to make one from 0 and not use any libraries or anything else.

If there are no tutorials, then the biggest concern I'm having is: how would I handle DLLs (or any dependency files for that matter) and/or registry entries.

Comment: I think that depends on whether you want to have the dlls separate to the installer exe.

Comment: WHY do you want to do this? It seems a strange thing to do when Visual Studio can make installers for you, which work reasonably well!

Comment: what do you mean you don't want to use libraries, what about WiX? Is there a particular reason you don't want to use them?

Comment: @AAT I don't want the installer to bundle my projects, but rather to BE a project. So this is an application I want to develop to maybe later sell or use for my clients.

Comment: Everything with doesn't generate MSI's is in the end a PITA IMHO - yes even systems such as the Nullsoft installer. That's because only MSI can properly be deplyoed and maintained in a corporate environment, while exe-based installers cannot. That said, I suggest that you do one version with a proper MSI installer (WiX to the rescue) and one which is deployed as portable version, that is, without the need for any installation process (can be run directly and doesn't mess with the system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple setup creator that contains the .exe and .DLL files of your "bin/Release" then use this to make a "Check for Update" function:

["Check for Update" function](http://themech.net/2008/05/adding-check-for-update-option-in-csharp/)