# How to add an Acces Database to my published C# program?

Tags: c#, ms-access

So i made a program in C# and added an Acces Database to it (.accdb). I can use it easily while in Debug mode, but after I publish the application it gives me an error everytime i try to use it (it says it can't find it).

My question is how can i make it so that it also installs the .accdb file with the program?

In the debug folder, the .accdb file is in the same folder as the .exe, so i need to make it install in the same folder as the .exe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251062/c-sharp-how-to-make-an-installer-for-my-application) how to add an installation wizard to your application, and you should then add the .accdb file to the installed files.

You will still probably have to check if the file exists, and if not - notify the user and quit, or create a blank template of your database and work with no data.

Comment: If this is really your answer, I should probably close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: He not only had the problem of including the file in the installation, but also the fact the file was missing, which can also happen when including in the installation, as the user can rename or remove, etc. Did I understand the OP correctly?

Comment: This helped me alot as I didn't know i can make my own Setup and that's why i didn't find the other answer. Sorry for that and thanks Nathan.