# Use a project with CsvHelper library, on other computer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, csvhelper

I have a project that uses the CsvHelper library.
As we know, in order to use this library, we need to install it (with Visual Studio helping, for instance).

So my question is, if I want to run my project on another computer, there is a way to do that without install the CsvHelper on the other computer before?

I mean that I want to give the project with the library together, and when we open the project on the other computer, we will get the CsvHelper with it.

Comment: Typically, if you copy everything in the bin folder, you will have all you need. Have you tried that?

Comment: Thanks for your answer :-) what it means to copy to bin folder? What should I copy?

Comment: Are you trying to share the source code or the compiled project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make an installer for my C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251062/how-to-make-an-installer-for-my-c-sharp-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following steps to use a project with csvhelper in anther computer.

First, please install nuget-package csvhelper in your app.

Second, you can right click your app and choose Properties.

Third, please click Application files and ensure that csvhelper.dll is included.

[image]

Fourth, you can publish your app.

Finally, after you copy the publish folder to another computer and install it in the computer, you can run the app with csvhelper.