# Installer for an C# Application

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I try to create an installer for an C# WPF App with VS2019.
For a single app with the "Setup Project" or "Setup Wizard" of VS these solutions works fine.

For my purpose, I need four steeps inside a single installer:

- Install Docker
- Run a batch file
- Visual C++ Redistributable
- Install C# WPF App

Is this possible, without to write an own Installer-Program?

Thx in advance

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need the end user to install Docker?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make an installer for my C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251062/how-to-make-an-installer-for-my-c-sharp-application)

You should definitely NOT write your own installer. If the VS support is not available try something free like Wix Toolset, or something other paid tool that makes the job easier (WiX is very powerful, but it has a steep learning curve).